# Utilizar Cluster ya Existente CDK AWS

Tags: javascript, nodejs, aws, amazon-rds

Usamos bases de datos en aws y estamos creando un Iac para desplegar los entornos necesarios en base de datos, el codigo lo hace bastante bien, pero tengo un problema, es que cuando hago el `"cdk deploy"` de cada base de datos, este crea un cluster nuevo por lo que no se puede.
y estoy intentando unificar que todo quede dentro de uno mismo que ya existe y esta nombrado como `"clusterdev"` en aws, el codigo que he creado es el siguiente.

```
const { DatabaseClusterEngine, 
    DatabaseCluster,    
    CfnDBCluster,
    AuroraMysqlEngineVersion, ServerlessCluster, Credentials, DatabaseSecret, AuroraCapacityUnit, SubnetGroup } = require('aws-cdk-lib/aws-rds');
const { SecurityGroup, Port, InstanceType, SubnetType } = require('aws-cdk-lib/aws-ec2');
const { Duration, RemovalPolicy } = require('aws-cdk-lib');
const {Aspects} = require('aws-cdk-lib');


const createRelationalDatabase = (
    scope,
    { name, vpc, secretManagerKey, encriptionKey,
        mySqlVersion, username, dbSubnets, subnetGroup,
        cluster, securityGroup, clusterSecurityGroups, defaultDatabaseName,
        dbExists, clusterIdentifier, dbSecurityGroupId, secretArn
    }
) => {
    if (!scope) throw new Error('Error scope missing');
    if (!vpc) throw new Error('Error vpc missing');
    if (!mySqlVersion) throw new Error('Error mySqlVersion missing');
    if (!name) throw new Error('Error name missing');
    if (!username) throw new Error('Error username missing');
    if (!cluster) throw new Error('Error cluster missing');
    if (!clusterSecurityGroups) throw new Error('Error clusterSecurityGroups missing');
    if (!securityGroup) throw new Error('Error securityGroup missing');
    if (!dbExists) {
        const engine = DatabaseClusterEngine.auroraMysql({
            version: AuroraMysqlEngineVersion[mySqlVersion],
        });
        // Crear SG de serverles cluster
        dbSecurityGroup = new SecurityGroup(
            scope,
            `${securityGroup.name}`,
            {
                vpc,
                securityGroupName: `${securityGroup.name}`,
            }
        );
        dbSecurityGroup.applyRemovalPolicy(RemovalPolicy.RETAIN);

        // Crear las reglas de entrada de SG de base de datos para permitir ingreso de SG cluster
        clusterSecurityGroups.forEach(clusterSecurityGroup => {
            dbSecurityGroup.addIngressRule(
                clusterSecurityGroup,
                Port.tcp(securityGroup.port),
                securityGroup.description
            );
        });     

        snGroup = new SubnetGroup(scope, `${name}-subnet-group`, {
            description: subnetGroup.description,
            vpc,
            vpcSubnets: {
                subnets: dbSubnets
            }
        });
        snGroup.applyRemovalPolicy(RemovalPolicy.RETAIN);
        dbSecret = new DatabaseSecret(scope, `${name}-secret`, {
                encriptionKey: secretManagerKey,
                username: username,
                secretName: `${name}-rds-secret`
        });
        dbSecret.applyRemovalPolicy(RemovalPolicy.RETAIN);

        //console.log(dbSecret, username);
        const credentials = Credentials.fromSecret(dbSecret, username);

        // const relationalDb = new ServerlessCluster(scope, `${name}-db`, {
        //  engine,
        //  vpc,
        //  storageEncryptionKey: encriptionKey,
        //  backupRetention: Duration.days(cluster.backupRetention),
        //  clusterIdentifier: `${name}-cluster`,
        //  securityGroups: [ dbSecurityGroup ], 
        //  subnetGroup: snGroup,
        //  defaultDatabaseName,
        //  credentials: credentials,
        //  scaling: {
        //      maxCapacity: AuroraCapacityUnit.ACU_2,
        //      minCapacity: AuroraCapacityUnit.ACU_1, 
        //  }
        // });
        
        // create a db cluster
        // https://github.com/aws/aws-cdk/issues/20197#issuecomment-1117555047
        const relationalDb = new DatabaseCluster(scope, `${name}-db`, {         
            engine: DatabaseClusterEngine.AURORA_MYSQL,
            instances: 1,
            instanceProps: {
                vpc: vpc,
                instanceType: new InstanceType('serverless'),
                autoMinorVersionUpgrade: true,              
                securityGroups: [ dbSecurityGroup ], 
                vpcSubnets: {
                    subnets: dbSubnets
                }
            }           
        })
        relationalDb.applyRemovalPolicy(RemovalPolicy.RETAIN);

        // add capacity to the db cluster to enable scaling
        Aspects.of(relationalDb).add({
            visit(node) {
            if (node instanceof CfnDBCluster) {
                node.serverlessV2ScalingConfiguration = {
                minCapacity: 0.5, // min capacity is 0.5 vCPU
                maxCapacity: 1, // max capacity is 1 vCPU (default)
                }
            }
            },
        })

        return {
            relationalDb,
            dbSecret
        };
    } else {
        const dbSecurityGroup = SecurityGroup.fromSecurityGroupId(scope, `${securityGroup.name}`, dbSecurityGroupId);
        clusterSecurityGroups.forEach(clusterSecurityGroup => {
            dbSecurityGroup.addIngressRule(
                clusterSecurityGroup,
                Port.tcp(securityGroup.port),
                securityGroup.description
            );
        });
        const dbSecret = DatabaseSecret.fromSecretCompleteArn(scope, `${name}-secret`, secretArn);
        const relationalDb = ServerlessCluster.fromServerlessClusterAttributes(scope, `${name}-db`, {
            clusterIdentifier
        });
        return {
            relationalDb,
            dbSecret
        };
    }
};

module.exports = { createRelationalDatabase };
```

Lo que he intentando es lo siguiente.

```
const { DatabaseClusterEngine, DatabaseSecret } = require('aws-cdk-lib/aws-rds');
const { SecurityGroup, Port } = require('aws-cdk-lib/aws-ec2');
const { Duration, RemovalPolicy } = require('aws-cdk-lib');
const { Aspects } = require('aws-cdk-lib');

const createRelationalDatabase = (
    scope,
    {
      name,
      vpc,
      secretManagerKey,
      encriptionKey,
      mySqlVersion,
      username,
      dbSubnets,
      subnetGroup,
      cluster, // Nombre del clúster existente
      securityGroup,
      clusterSecurityGroups,
      defaultDatabaseName,
      dbExists,
      clusterIdentifier,
      dbSecurityGroupId,
      secretArn
    }
) => {
    if (!scope) throw new Error('Error scope missing');
    if (!vpc) throw new Error('Error vpc missing');
    if (!mySqlVersion) throw new Error('Error mySqlVersion missing');
    if (!name) throw new Error('Error name missing');
    if (!username) throw new Error('Error username missing');
    if (!cluster) throw new Error('Error cluster missing');
    if (!clusterSecurityGroups) throw new Error('Error clusterSecurityGroups missing');
    if (!securityGroup) throw new Error('Error securityGroup missing');
    if (!dbExists) {
        // Obtener referencias al clúster existente
        const existingCluster = DatabaseCluster.fromDatabaseClusterAttributes(scope, `${cluster}-cluster`, {
            clusterIdentifier: cluster
        });

        // Obtener la clave secreta para el clúster existente
        const dbSecret = DatabaseSecret.fromSecretArn(scope, `${name}-rds-secret`, secretArn);

        // Obtener credenciales desde la clave secreta
        const credentials = Credentials.fromSecret(dbSecret, username);

        // Configurar tu aplicación utilizando el clúster existente y las referencias de seguridad
        // ...

        return {
            relationalDb: existingCluster,
            dbSecret
        };
    } else {
        const dbSecurityGroup = SecurityGroup.fromSecurityGroupId(scope, `${securityGroup.name}`, dbSecurityGroupId);
        clusterSecurityGroups.forEach(clusterSecurityGroup => {
            dbSecurityGroup.addIngressRule(
                clusterSecurityGroup,
                Port.tcp(securityGroup.port),
                securityGroup.description
            );
        });
        const dbSecret = DatabaseSecret.fromSecretCompleteArn(scope, `${name}-secret`, secretArn);

        // Configurar tu aplicación utilizando el clúster existente y las referencias de seguridad
        // ...

        return {
            relationalDb: existingCluster,
            dbSecret
        };
    }
};
```

Como ven, he puesto las validaciones pertinentes y tambien usando `existingCluster`
para que valide que el cluster ya existe,

pero no he tenido el resultado esperado, de hecho cuando hago el deploy, crea todo bien sin problemas pero dentro del cluster no se crea la db que se ha configurado en el archivo yml el cual es este

```
relational:
  dbSecretParameter: /ASTRO/DB_SECRET
  name: astro-relational
  defaultDatabaseName: Astro
  mySqlVersion: '5.6.10.a'
  encriptionKey: arn:aws:kms:us-east-1:${/GLOBAL/ACCOUNT_NUMBER}:key/${/GLOBAL/KMS_RDS}
  secretManagerKey: arn:aws:kms:us-east-1:${/GLOBAL/ACCOUNT_NUMBER}:key/${/GLOBAL/KMS_SECRETS}
  username: AstroDatabaseAdmin
  securityGroup:
    name: astro-relational-db-sg
    port: 3306
    sgIngressRuleDescription: Ingress rule for consumer fargate cluster
  #clusterIdentifier: clusterdev  # Agregado el cluster existente
  backupRetention: 3
  subnetGroup:
    description: subnet group for astro relational database
```